# FBSDKMessengerSharer share audio not working

Tags: xcode, swift, facebook, audio, facebook-ios-sdk

I can successfully share video and picture using `FBSDKMessengerSharer` `shareVideo` and `shareImage` methods.

When I go to share an .mp3 file using `shareAudio` method, it seems to work as it should within my app, however when the file is sent in Facebook Messenger, it display error within facebook messenger when trying to play.

[image]

Any help would be amazing. I have been struggling with this for days.

Code to setup share button:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let button = FBSDKMessengerShareButton.rectangularButtonWithStyle(FBSDKMessengerShareButtonStyle.Blue);
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(_shareButtonPressed), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside);
    self.view.addSubview(button);

}
```

shareButtonPressed function:

```
func _shareButtonPressed() {        
    let audioUrl = NSURL(string: "<URL_TO_MY_MP3>/214.mp3")
    do {

        let mp3Data = try NSData(contentsOfURL: audioUrl!, options: NSDataReadingOptions())
        FBSDKMessengerSharer.shareAudio(mp3Data, withOptions: FBSDKMessengerShareOptions());
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }

}
```

Comment: some code sample would be great  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that the bytes in my MP3 files were not formatted correctly. Adding  mp3 header bytes solved the problem.